# How do I delete a specific list of lines from a text document?

Tags: c#

This is what I have but there isn't anything that talks about how to delete multiple specific lines, for example, from line 2 - 8.

```
var file = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(lsbMatches.SelectedItem.ToString()));//location
file.RemoveAt(2);// i want to change this to multiple lines
File.WriteAllLines(lsbMatches.SelectedItem.ToString(), file.ToArray());//location
```

Comment: You are probably better off using LINQ `Where` and passing an `IEnumerable` through to `WriteAllLines` as this is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RemoveRange because you have converted your text file into a list of strings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You're best option is to do :

```
file.RemoveRange(2, 6);
```